# Двухпанельный файловый менеджер с возможностью вешать теги

Tags: файлы, linux

Из-за определенных обстоятельств решил на домашний десктоп поставить линукс, окончательно перейдя на него. До этого момента имел дело только с консолью, поэтому gui-софт практически не знаю, в связи с чем и прошу вашего совета.

Я ищу обязательно **двухпанельный** файловый менеджер с возможностью вешать **теги** на файлы и папки - существует ли такой вообще?

Быть может это реализовано при помощи плагина в каком-нибудь общеизвестном менеджере?

Возможно есть такой, в котором реализована одна фича, но отсутствует другая?

Comment: что имеется в виду? "вешать теги"

Comment: Ровно то, что написано, а именно возможность назначать теги на группу файлов/папок с возможностью выборки по ним и дальнейшей манипуляции.п.с. вам нужно было комментировать, как я сейчас, а не отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

Нигде не видел подобной реализации вообще.

Вы не путайте теги в web где они действительно нужны в материалах, и каталог где все хранится в папка для удобства.

Вряд ли найдешь такую реализацию ибо она хоть и звучит интересно.

узай как и все MC. :)

По-этому совет, не стоит усложнять жизнь. Многие вещи нужны только в нужных местах, там где от них есть толк. Любая ОСь на то и создается в рамках чего-то, чтобы потом с ней было удобно работать. Теги только в web, там им и место, а в системе ИМХО это бредово. Лишний геморрой т.к. реализация тегов в системе - глупая затея.

**//update**

Потому что это действительно интересно, но это берет начало в WEBe.

Там это имеет место, там это было придумано и там оно имеет популярность. В ОС подобная реализация была бы бредом ИМХО. Зачем там это нужно?

> Медиаколлекция

Ну у меня тоже дома на серваке 10Тб мультимедии, фильмы и музыка. И все разложено по папка. А еще на серваке есть web сервер, на котором есть инфа по каздой папке, и вот там (т.к. я по большей части именно web программист) находится внутренний ресурс с описаниями всего что нужно, и теги (допустим у фильма всегда есть актеры, а актеры играют в разных фильмах) ну вот там и реализованы теги но немного не в привычном для понимания формате.

Собственно вот у меня сделано так. Может и велосипед, но меня устраивает. Так что не знаю на самом деле нужно ли именно в систему добавлять теги т.к. суть системы в хранении инфы как таковой и предоставлении инструментов для обработки её. Но вот, лично моё мнение, привязывать в систему теги немного неразумно.

Comment: @shrek Нет, не путаю. Мне этого очень не хватает в обработке моей гигантской медиаколлекции, которую удобней рассматривать как раз как хранилище неких объектов, а не просто как файлы - хочу, что-бы этот функционал поддерживался именно на уровне менеджера, и система тут ни при чем.**mc** я "узнал" и с удовольствием пользуюсь им уже лет десять как.К чему ваше лирическое отступление про ОСи и системы? И вообще, вы не последовательны: говорите, что это звучит интересно, и в следующем абзаце называете бредом и глупой затеей…

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @shrek Файловый менеджер - вполне себе программа прикладная, который при желании можн безболезненно снести и заменить его любым другим, **можно и вовсе без него обходиться - к системе он не имеет ни малейшего отношения**! Вы, должно быть, путаете его с **файловыми системами**, которых также существует великое множество, пока, на сколько мне известно, ни одна теги не поддерживает, хотя идея эта не новая и обсуждается довольно давно. И мне она не кажется бредовой - попробуйте набрать в консоли:    mount|awk '{print $5}'

Comment: @shrek **продолжение** и вы увидите системы, используемые у вас на компе - спорю на что угодно, что их будет несколько разных - своя под каждую задачу. Так вот я бы с удовольствием завел бы **фс** с поддержкой тегов на отдельном разделе, специально заточенную под медиа. Это все мечты, пока я ищу именно **файловый менеджер** - очень удивился, когда не увидел таковой в первых строчках гугла…Прошу прощенья за ликбез, очевидно, что недопонимание у нас вышло именно в терминологии.

Comment: @shrek **продолжение** Если бы мне не нужно было периодически работать с данными в моей коллекции, то мне вполне хватило бы справочной системы как у вас. Уж не знаю, почему вы ее называете велосипедом, по моему это вполне крепкая справочная система, если она конечно же сделана должным образом.

Comment: @shrek **продолжение** У меня только музыка, и мне время от времени приходится искать, допустим, исполнения конкретного произведения, сделанные определенным дирижером с определенным оркестром до определенного года. Конвертировать в другой формат, писать на диски, просто копировать… Вариантов выборок очень много, и когда количество папок приближается к сотне тысяч, это становится непростой задачей - очень хочется ее хоть как-то облегчить.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то пользовался doublecmd, не я, но я видел две панельки, поэтому вот линк - [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/).